# how can i draw Approximating a Derivative graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{frame}{Forward-Difference Formula to Approximate $f'(x_0)$}
        \begin{block}{} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->, thick] (-1,0) -- (10,0) node(xline)[right] {$x$};
            \draw[->, thick] (0,-1) -- (0,6)  node(yline)[above] {$y$};  
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to TeX-SE. Could you be more specific about what you want to achieve? Do you want to animate the line that approches the tangent? Or do you just want to draw something like the picture you posted?

Comment: i want to draw the picture i posted. but i dont know how i start. if i learn i am new latex. if i can learn the codes of the graphic in the picture i can apply it myself for others

Answer (score 3):

So, if you're starting from nowhere, this could be a bit difficult to achieve by yourself. I'll give you a copy of what I give to my students in the derivative course.

It uses `tikz-euclide` package for my personal convenience, but you could do it with a plain TikZ code.

Of course, with a bit of understanding, you can easily adapt this code to your own desire.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    
        \draw (-1,0) -- (7.5,0) (0,-.5) -- (0,4.5); % Axis
        \node[below left=2pt and 2pt] at (0,0) {$O$}; % Origin
        
        % Function curve        
        \begin{scope}       
            \clip (-1,0) rectangle (7.5,4.5);
            \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.5:7.5] plot(\x,{0.3*((\x)-3.5)*((\x)-3.5)+0.5}); 
        \end{scope}
        
        \def\xA{2.5} \def\yA{0.8}
        \coordinate (A) at (\xA,\yA);
        \draw[dashed] (\xA,0) node[below=2pt] {$a$} -- (A) -- (0,\yA) node[left] {$f(a)$};
                
        \def\xM{6.5} \def\yM{3.2}
        \coordinate (M) at (\xM,\yM);
        \draw[dashed] (\xM,0) node[below] {$a+h$} -- (M) -- (0,\yM) node[left] {$f(a+h)$};
        \begin{scope}       
            \clip (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (7.5,4.5);

            % Series of lines all through point A
            \foreach \xN/\yN in {6.5/3.2,6/2.38,5.5/1.7,5/1.18,4.5/0.8,4/0.58,3.5/0.5}
                {
                \coordinate (N) at (\xN,\yN);
                \tkzDrawPoint[size=8](N)
                \tkzDrawLine[add=2 and 3,color=red](A,N)
                }   
        \end{scope}
        
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=green!50!black,smooth,samples=100,domain=0.5:5] plot(\x,{-0.6*(\x)+2.3}) node[above] {$T$};            
        
        \tkzDrawPoints[size=8](A,M)
        \tkzLabelPoint[above=3pt](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above left](M){$M$}
        
        %%%%Arrows alongside the curve
        \foreach \a/\b in {6.55/6.9, 6/6.35, 5.5/5.85, 4.9/5.35, 4.35/4.75}
            {
            \draw[<-,>=stealth,line width=1pt,color=orange,smooth,samples=100,domain=\a:\b] plot(\x,{0.32*((\x)-3.95)*((\x)-3.95)+0.55});
            }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Derivative]